# How do I charge a stored credit card with the payflow pro API?

Tags: c#, paypal, transactions, pci-compliance, payflowpro

I'm using the PayflowNETAPI class of the PayflowPro API (Payflow_dotNET.dll) to submit a transaction to store credit cards so my company doesn't have to (for PCI Compliant reassons). 
I'm using the PNREF from the credit card store transaction to make reference transaction but I keep getting "RESULT=2&PNREF=&RESPMSG=Invalid tender"
I've tried Authorization, Capture, and Sale transactions and they all give the same result. What am I doing wrong?

I've read through the Payflow Gateway Developer Guide and Reference several times (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/payflow/integration-guide/). All the examples for Authorization, Capture, and Sale transactions have the credit card information in the request. There is some small sections that explain and outline credit card uploads but never use the result of the request in a reference transaction.

Below is a sample application and the output

```
string creditCardUploadRequest = "TRXTYPE=L&TENDER=C&ACCT=4111111111111111&EXPDATE=1218&CVV2=250&BILLTOFIRSTNAME=Homer&BILLTOLASTNAME=Simpson&BILLTOSTREET=350 5th Ave&BILLTOCITY=New York&BILLTOSTATE=NY&BILLTOZIP=10118&BILLTOCOUNTRY=840&USER=<USER>&VENDOR=<VENDOR>&PARTNER=<PARTNER>&PWD=<PASSWORD>&VERBOSITY=HIGH";

var client = new PayPal.Payments.Communication.PayflowNETAPI(HostAddress: "pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com", HostPort: 443, Timeout: 90);
var ccUploadResponse = client.SubmitTransaction(ParamList: creditCardUploadRequest, RequestId: PayflowUtility.RequestId);

//place the responses into collection
var payPalCollection = new NameValueCollection();

foreach (string element in ccUploadResponse.Split('&'))
{
    string[] Temp = element.Split('=');
    payPalCollection.Add(Temp[0], Temp[1]);
}

Console.WriteLine("creditCardUploadRequest succeeded = {0}", payPalCollection.Get("RESPMSG") == "Approved");

string authorizationRequest = "TRXTYPE=A&ORIGID=" + payPalCollection.Get("PNREF") + "&INVNUM=ORD123456&AMT=50&COMMENT1=My Product Sale&USER=<USER>&VENDOR=<VENDOR>&PARTNER=<PARTNER>&PWD=<PASSWORD>&VERBOSITY=HIGH";
var authorizationResponse = client.SubmitTransaction(ParamList: authorizationRequest, RequestId: PayflowUtility.RequestId);

foreach (string element in authorizationResponse.Split('&'))
{
    Console.WriteLine(element);
}
Console.WriteLine("\nDONE");
Console.ReadKey();
```

OUTPUT:

creditCardUploadRequest succeeded = True

RESULT=2

PNREF=A7X08AB571EC

RESPMSG=Invalid tender

DONE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second call you are missing the variable "TENDER=C" . Add that and it should be fine .

```
"string authorizationRequest = "TRXTYPE=A&ORIGID=" + payPalCollection.Get("PNREF") + "&INVNUM=ORD123456&AMT=50&COMMENT1=My Product Sale&USER=<USER>&VENDOR=<VENDOR>&PARTNER=<PARTNER>&PWD=<PASSWORD>&VERBOSITY=HIGH"
```

Comment: Didn't work. I added TENDER=C and got the following error:

RESULT=117

PNREF=<PNREF>

RESPMSG=Failed merchant rule check

Comment: To get rid if this error you need to to turn on the reference transaction in the manager account . Go to the manager account -- Account Administration --> Transaction settings and turn on the reference txn and wait for an hour and it should work fine .

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. I'm not an account admin so I'll have to ask my boss if this works. I'll report back as soon as I can.

Comment: turning on reference transactions in PayflowPro worked. thanks